# Is it possible to use SSIS in order to fill multiple tables with inheritance at the same time?

Tags: sql-server, inheritance, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got an MS SQL database with 3 inherent tables. A general one called "Tools" and two more specific ones "DieCastTool" and "Deburrer".

My task is it to get data out of an old MS Access "database". My Problem is, that I have to do a lot of search and filtering stuff untill I've got my data that I'd like to import into the new DB. So finally I don't want to do theses steps several times but populate the 3 tables at the same time.
Therefore I am using da Dataflowtarget in which I am not selecting a certain table, but using an sql select statement (with inner joins on the id columns) to receive all the fields of the 3 tables. Then I match the columns and in my opinion it should work. And it does as long as I only select the columns of the "Tools" table to be filled. When adding the columns of the child-tables, unfortunately it does not and returns me the ErrorCode -1071607685 => "No status is available"

I can think of 2 reasons why my solution does not work:

1. SSIS simply can't handle inheritance in SQL Tables and sees them as individual tables. (Maybe SSIS even can't handle filling multiple tables in one Dataflowtarget element?)
2. I am using SSIS in a wrong way.

Would be nice if someone could confirm/decline reason 1 because I have not found anything on this topic.

Comment: If I were to summarize, source data is very ugly and cleaning it is complex. Due to these complexities, your preference is to clean the data once and then write to up to 3 tables in sequence to respect the potential FK relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, SSIS is not aware of table relationships. Think of it as: SSIS is aware of physical objects only, not your logical model.

I didn't understand how You got that error. Anyway, here are solutions:

1. if there are no FK constraints between those tables, You can use one source component, one multicast and 3 destinations in one dataflow
2. if there are FK constraints and You can disable them, then use
   Execute SQL Task to disable (or drop) constraints, add the same
   dataflow as in 1. and add another Execute SQL Task to enable (or
   create) constraints
3. if there are FK constraints and You can't disable them, You can use
   one dataflow to read all data and pass it to subsequent dataflows to
   fill table by table. See
   [SSIS Pass Datasource Between Control Flow Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571899/ssis-pass-datasource-between-control-flow-tasks).

Comment: Thanks I solved my problem with solution no. 3 => first reading out the data, doing all the filtering stuff and writing that data into a temporary storage and afterwards filling the tables with that data separately

Comment: btw it did not work using a multicast to fill the DieCastTool and Deburrer tables (at the same time), I had to split it into separate dataflows

Comment: @Da_Wolf, interesting, why? is there pk/fk relationship between those two? I do this on regular basis

Comment: Yes there is a pk/fk relationship between those tables